# Building cross-compiler - compiling gcc errors

Tags: c, gcc, cross-compiling, osdev

I'm trying to build a cross-compiler and following this tutorial: [GCC Cross-Compiler - OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler). I've downloaded the newest gcc and some libraries etc. mentioned in the article.

Problem is at building GCC itself, specifically at `make all-gcc` command. After running this command I'm getting these errors:

```
In file included from ../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/graphite.c:88:0:
../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/graphite-poly.h:398:43: error: ‘isl_constraint’ has not been declared
 extern void print_isl_constraint (FILE *, isl_constraint *);
                                           ^
../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/graphite-poly.h:402:35: error: variable or field ‘debug_isl_constraint’ declared void
 extern void debug_isl_constraint (isl_constraint *);
                                   ^
../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/graphite-poly.h:402:35: error: ‘isl_constraint’ was not declared in this scope
../../gcc-5.2.0/gcc/graphite-poly.h:402:51: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
 extern void debug_isl_constraint (isl_constraint *);
                                                   ^
make[1]: *** [graphite.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/_tos/src/build-gcc/gcc'
make: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
```

I guess that I could just repair those pieces of code and it'd work fine, but is there any other, better solution?

Thanks

Comment: What version of the ISL library are you using? the development package might be something like libisl-dev (you didn't mention the platform). It seems that particular versions of ISL will cause this issue. Apparently a patch was committed (and some have found ISL 0.14-1 to work) to fix this with isl 0.15. See https://www.mail-archive.com/gcc-bugs@gcc.gnu.org/msg460981.html and patches here https://www.mail-archive.com/gcc-bugs@gcc.gnu.org/msg462373.html

Comment: I'm using `isl-0.15` from [this site](http://isl.gforge.inria.fr/) (as mentioned in the tutorial). How is it that problem in `gcc/graphite.c` is caused by ISL?

Comment: @Michael I've changed my ISL to version 0.14.1 and it works now. Thank you very much.